# Information about instantiating ANNs with a larger outup size than input size?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset

I am trying to locate information which discusses any of the technical implications of training an ANN against a data set where the number of outputs is larger (in my case 2x) than the number of inputs. I am having a very difficult time finding anything.

Though I am not completely convinced that it should exist. My only reasoning, if it can even be called that, is that in class and projects I have always had the case where the number of inputs is larger than the number of outputs. With that motif it then just seems very odd to try to fit a data set that has the opposite property.

*Does anyone know of any sources for this, any general information on this type of data set?*

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a problem. Problems such as image-superresolution which use neural networks often involve the output size being much larger than the input size. Other examples are the decoder half of an encoder-decoder network and semantic segmentation, where the input is HxWx3 but the output is HxWxK and K can be much bigger than 3.

There isn't any fundamental reason that having more outputs than inputs should cause problems with NNs.